# Transposing columns as rows and rows as columns in OpenRefine

Tags: pivot-table, transpose, openrefine

Simple newbie problem to tranpose cells and rows but can't figure it out: I downloaded WDI data where the years are in columns and the countries and indicators are rows (image 1). I know how to transpose the years as rows (image 2), but how can I also send the indicators as colums so it looks like the third image?

Many thanks!

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

[image: image 3]

Answer (score 1):

If you have this:

[image]

Choose « Columnize by key/value columns... » in the Transpose menu item of the column menu.

[image]

Choose the two columns, one for the column names and the other for the values.

[image]

And you should get this…

[image]

Don't forget to vote if you like my answer.

Regards,
Antoine

Comment: Ça marche! Merci Antoine :-)